# Returning to a specific point after exception is raised in Python 3

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, syntax, return

My code raises an exception error if a number outside of the designated range is entered.
Upon doing so it returns control to my main function.

What I would like it to do is return to the question so the user can try again. How/can
I make it return to the variable for another input?

```py
def student_entry():
    try:
        num_students = int(input('How many students do you have? : ' ))
        print()
        for student in range (1, num_students + 1):
            print('enter data for student #', student, sep='')
            print()
            name = input('Student Name: ')
            print()
            average = int(input('What is the students average : '))
            print()

            try:
                if average >=0 and average <= 100:

                    mainfile.write(str('Student Name: ') + str(name) +'\n')
                    mainfile.write(str('Grade Average: ') + str(average) + '\n')

                else:
                    raise ValueError

            except ValueError as AverageError:

                print('invalid average. Please try again.')
                return average

    except ValueError:

        print('an error has occured')

    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you catch the `ValueError` you are breaking out of the `student_entry()` function as you `return average.` You can avoid this by using a `while` loop, which you can break out of only after you satisfy the average conditions and write your data out.

```
while True:
    average = int(input('What is the students average : '))
    try:
        if average > 0 and average <= 100:
            # write to file
            break # this will break out of the while loop
        else:
            raise  ValueError
    except ValueError:
           print("Invalid average - try again")
```

Using `while True` will mean the loop will run repeatedly until we explicitly break out of it using the `break` statement - so the user will be prompted to enter an input until they satisfy the condition that their average was greater than zero and less than or equal to 100.

More details on `while` loops in Python can be seen at https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your input in a while loop:

```
average = -1
while (average < 0) or (avergage > 100)
   average = int(input('What is the students average : '))
print()
```

You can get a little bit more creative with this in terms of addition conditionals that explain to your user why the input was invalid or such, but that should be enough to get you going.